# OAuth linking with actions on google

Tags: google-oauth, actions-on-google

hello im trying to setup account linking for actions on google. when testing in the simulator there is no debugInfo.sharedDebugInfo info in the response. my question is what am i missing to get this to be populated. ive set the welcome intent to be signedIn via the api.ai console as well as all the other necessary fields for oauth linking.

[view of the setting on api.ai console(signin required)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdjlK.png)

[view of the setting on api.ai console(oauth form)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkCCx.png)

Comment: check this post to verify your configuration - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288981/how-to-authenticate-user-with-just-a-google-account-on-actions-on-google

Answer (score 0):

Once you enable the "**sign-in required for Welcome intent**", you should see it right after you ask the "**can i talk to myAgent**" question.
Here is what I see:

```
Request
{
    "query": "can i talk to myAgent",
    "accessToken": "ya29.GlzXA38i6oBr0UD5CxXzstBaYFpbQF0tL16jK7tefC2_lWvofj79TbCmrDS1jedhxc_-LJp0w6PW3CJN5wL3oOFoqSMAZ8TbAKiMW6SKcUM65DUVdsSWC65nc_Oezg"
}

Response
{
    "response": "It looks like your myAgent account is not linked yet. You can link myAgent to your Google Account from the Google Home app.",
    "audioResponse": "//NExAASi..."content_copy,
    "debugInfo": {
        "sharedDebugInfo": [
            {
                "name": "Account Linking Url",
                "debugInfo": "https://assistant.google.com/services/auth/handoffs/auth/start?provider=myAgent-156006_dev&return_url=https://www.google.com/"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```