# How to create account linking?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, api-ai

I'd like to create AccountLinking to recognize users.

I tried with reference to the links below.

- https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking
- [How to authenticate user with just a Google account on Actions on Google?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288981/how-to-authenticate-user-with-just-a-google-account-on-actions-on-google)

And then when i tried Accout Linking on the actions on Google simulator.

I got this result.

```
{
"response": "It looks like your Test account is not linked yet",
"audioResponse": "//NExAARc...",
"debugInfo": {
    "sharedDebugInfo": [
        {
            "name": "Account Linking Url",
            "debugInfo": "https://assistant.google.com/services/auth/handoffs/auth/start?provider=my_project_name_dev&scopes=email+name&return_url=https://www.google.com/"
        }
    ]
}}
```

And then I did a copy & paste that link into my browser.

But i got this result.

```
400. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_scope

Some requested scopes were invalid. {valid=
[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email], invalid=[name]}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` scope isn't a valid scope. (And the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` scope is valid, but deprecated.)

See https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#google_sign-in for the scopes you want, but probably `profile` and `email` are the ones you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question.The problem is solved:)

Comment: Glad it helps! If it answered your question, please upvote and/or accept the answer using the controls to the left of the answer text.