# DialogFlow: Google Calendar Event function from Google Actions (Oauth2)?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-calendar-api, google-assist-api

I have created an agent in DialogFlow that interacts with the user giving her the ability to check for details like demographic from a back-end database. I have achieved this using Fulfillment/Webhook calls and have successfully parsed/returned different types of Responses to the user to play with. I have tested this on both an Android device and the Google Actions Simulator.

Now, what I want to achieve is to give user the ability to "Set a Reminder" on a platform like Google Calendar or similar through my App. By default, Google Assistant does this by simply telling it to ["remind me..."](https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/00000052f28bc172) and Google creates a reminder in the calendar. But as soon as I invoke my app, the Assistant is out of scope so using the "remind me" command won't work. I want to use the Google Calendar for example to create a reminder through my agent so that the user is notified at the due time.

I understand that when the user invokes an App in Google Assistant, she is using her Google credentials so I guess if I want to use the App to create a reminder, I should have the option. I have had a look at the Calendar API but I am not sure if I should proceed that way. Is there a better way of achieving this?

Please note, I want to use a reminder service that is available to the user without subscribing to a third-party service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for all those who are facing the same issue, here is what I did:

1. First created an account on https://auth0.com
2. Followed this [guide](https://www.jovo.tech/blog/google-action-account-linking-auth0/) to configure the necessary settings to link to Google Assistant (ignored the Jovo part)
3. Used Auth0 [guide](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/google) to configure and link to my Google project credentials (ignored the Admins SDK Service part)
4. Now when I run my Google Actions App on the device, a button "Link [App Name] to Google" showed up. Clicking on that "signed me in".
5. Parsed the response in my webhook to grab `originalRequest.data.user.accessToken`

This is the token mentioned in @lukedavis answer. The next step was to use the token to execute a call to the Calendar API. Upon trying that, I am facing a different problem which I am trying to find the solution for. But the above should assist those who wish get the accessToken.

Answer (score 1):

The Calendar API is the way to go. Details [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth).

In those docs you'll see reference to the **access token**, which you can get by using the helper intent *askForSignIn* (example of use [here](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-helper-intents-nodejs/blob/master/functions/helper-intents/ask-for-sign-in.js) in one of Google's example projects).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. Furthermore, I found these:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218120/authenticate-google-calendar-on-api-ai-with-google-actions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218120/authenticate-google-calendar-on-api-ai-with-google-actions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44589700/google-actions-access-to-calendar-api-with-access-token-fails