# Google Action API.ai Account linking debugging URL returning 500

Tags: google-oauth, actions-on-google, api-ai

I’ve followed this tutorial https://apiai-aws-heroku-nodejs-bots.blogspot.co.uk/2017/07/steps-for-apiai-and-google-account.html but when I go and grab by debugging URL which happens to be https://assistant.google.com/services/auth/handoffs/auth/start?provider=allergology-5fa9c_dev&scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.resource.calendar&return_url=https://www.google.com/ and paste it into a new window I get Error 500 but no explanation.

I also tried from an incognito window. It does ask for my email and password but then returns the same error.

I’ve used Implicit Grant Type and I don’t have Add quick account linking enabled please ket me know if that’s not right?

When I try the CURL URL I get the message {“status”:{“code”:401,“errorType”:“unauthorized”,“errorDetails”:“Authentication parameters missing”}}

UPDATE - now when I try the basic Talk to Allergology action on the simulator I don’t even get the debug info anymore, but the message “Sorry this action is not available in simulation” :frowning:

Could you please help?
thanks
Morena

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to work out what I need to do by following this answer [How to authenticate user with just a Google account on Actions on Google?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288981/how-to-authenticate-user-with-just-a-google-account-on-actions-on-google)
In my case - Configure your project (in the cloud console) so that the Calendar API is enabled and that the OAuth2 client is correctly configured.
I also switched from Implicit Grant Type to Authorisation Code.
My app is almost working, I am now having other issues, but at some point the Access Token was coming through with the request.