# Account linking Actions on Google with App Engine Standard

Tags: google-oauth, actions-on-google, api-ai

I have an App Engine Standard project for API.AI fulfilment webhook. Users interact with my app through chat (Google Assistant) only—**no** Web interface. In summary, the app is a chat backend.

My app requires user's email to send updates. I read that I need [account linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/).

Based on [this answer in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44296039/193550), this is *exactly* what I did:

1. In **GCP console → APIs & services → Credentials**, I created new
   *OAuth 2.0 client ID*, with *Authorized redirect URI*: https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/[my-project-id].
2. In **Actions on Google console → Account linking**, I chose *Authorization code* with:

   - *Client ID* and *Client secret* copied from previous step
   - *Authorization URL*: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
   - *Token URL*: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
   - *Scopes*: `profile` and `email` (initially I put fully namespaced, e.g. `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` but somehow it got "shortened")
   - *Testing instructions*: A dummy Google account I created
3. In **API.AI console → Integrations → Google Assistant**, *Sign in required for welcome intent* is ticked.

The whole setup *kinda* works. Here's how it goes in the simulator:

1. Typed, "Talk to [my app]"
2. Received response, with login URL in the debug tab
3. Copy pasted the URL, login successful, redirected to Google home page
4. Back to simulator, typed: Talk to [my app]
5. Connected (auth code is passed in webhook calls, and my app can query user's email)

Two issues:

1. Why do I need to type `Talk to [my app]` twice?
2. My submission is rejected because "Your provided testing instructions either did not work correctly or were not substantial enough. Please ensure that you are providing everything needed for us to test your app, and that all credentials you provide work correctly."

Where did I do wrong?

**EDIT:** I tried using Android 6, it says "It looks like your [project] account is not linked yet," and there's a button to link. Upon clicking, it shows Google Account selector, but clicking it doesn't do anything (and no request to my server).

Comment: Do you have any answer on how to avoid typing Talk to twice now?
About the rejected submission, did you create an account in your auth serv so that they can test your app with it?