# Is there any way to authenticate the users for my google assistant app?

Tags: authentication, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, conversation-scope

I am developing an app for Google assistant and I need a suggestion about the authentication of users for my app so that i can manage their data according to their unique id. I am using Firebase as the database and I think that authenticating the user with a Gmail account is the best way to go about it. So is this possible? I'm also taking other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options here, depending on your needs.

If all you want to do is track repeat visitors to your Action, then you can use the anonymous *userId* that is available. This isn't really "authentication" and it certainly isn't a user identity, but if you get the same userId from a session, you know it is the same user that visited before with that userId.

If you already have accounts for your system, then going with Account Linking, as @ido-green has suggested is preferable, although significantly more complicated to setup.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - You can authenticate you users in your assistant app.
You will need to use the OAuth 2.0 flows and follow these steps:
https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking

Btw, there is a good question and great answer on how to do it here: [How to authenticate user with just a Google account on Actions on Google?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288981/how-to-authenticate-user-with-just-a-google-account-on-actions-on-google)

(!) One important thing to remember is that are the moment you need to use your own OAuth server and not use providers.

Comment: @kvk30 I'm not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate a bit? Thx!

Comment: I want details of the user, need to show them in my actions-on-google app. Is there any way to do that feature?