# Unable to Authorize users using Implicit / Authorization flow in google actions

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to link to the account :

Here is my **google cloud function**

```
var AuthHandler = function() {
    this.googleSignIn = googleSignIn;
    this.googleSignInCallback = googleSignInCallback;

}

function googleSignIn(req, res, next) {
    passport = req._passport.instance;

    passport.authenticate('google',{scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    state:"google",response_type:"token"},

    function(err, user, info) {
console.log(user);
    })(req,res,next);

};

function googleSignInCallback(req, res, next) {
    passport = req._passport.instance;
    passport.authenticate('google',function(err, user, info) {
        if(err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        if(!user) {
            return res.redirect('http://localhost:8000');
        }
        console.log(user._json.token);
        // /res.redirect('/');
       res.redirect('https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/xxxxxx#access_token=' + user._json.token + '&token_type=bearer&state=google')


    })(req,res,next);
};

module.exports = AuthHandler;
```

**In google Action Console** :

I have created the implicit flow and gave my authorisation url as follows:

```
https://[region]-[projectid].cloudfunctions.net/[functionname]/auth/google
```

**Error :**

this is the browser Url

```
https://assistant.google.com/services/auth/handoffs/auth/complete?state=xxxx&code=xxxxxx
```

on which the following error is displayed

> The parameter "state" must be set in the query string.

**Update 1**

Before starting this implementation , i have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288981/how-to-authenticate-user-with-just-a-google-account-on-actions-on-google) Solution to create the Authentication.

Problems in this Approach :

1.As stated in the Documentation it is not redirecting to google.com and i'm unable to access the `token` using the `APIAI` SDK in javascript. but still i can see the `Access token` in emulator . for better understanding adding images

[image: Unable to redirect to the Google]

Here is my simulator O/P

```
{

  "response": {

  "debug": {
    "agentToAssistantDebug": {

    "assistantToAgentDebug": {
      "assistantToAgentJson": "{"accessToken\":\"xxxxxx\""
    }
  },
  "errors": []
}
```

**Update 2 :**

So i have started creating with implicit flow and here is my complete [repo](https://github.com/Webrusterkk/AI_Implict)

Comment: I'm not clear what these functions are or what is calling them. Are they supposed to be an OAuth2 server? Are they supposed to be called as the Action webhook?

Comment: @Prisoner , yes, i'm trying to create the Oauth server , i have followed your previous answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288981/how-to-authenticate-user-with-just-a-google-account-on-actions-on-google) , let me update these details in question so that you can go through them easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After battling with it i have achieved it , as there is no proper articles about creation of own Oauth Server that implements the Google Action , this might helpful for future users.

**Authorization Endpoint**

```
  app.get('/authorise', function(req, res) {
     req.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxx';
      // with your own mechanism after successful
        //login you need to create a access token for the generation of 
     //authorization code and append it to this header;

    var request = new Request(req);
    var response = new Response(res);

     oauth.authorize(request, response).then(function(success) {     
     // https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/YOUR_PROJECT_ID?
      //code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&state=STATE_STRING
      var toredirect = success.redirectUri +"?code="+success.code 
            +"&state="+request.query.state ;
      return res.redirect(toredirect);  
    }).catch(function(err){
      res.status(err.code || 500).json(err)
    }) });
```

**Token Endpoint :**

```
 app.all('/oauth/token', function(req,res,next){
    var request = new Request(req);
    var response = new Response(res);

    oauth
      .token(request,response)
      .then(function(token) {
        // Todo: remove unnecessary values in response
        return res.json(token)
      }).catch(function(err){
        return res.status(500).json(err)
      })
  });
```

After creation of this endpoints publish to the Google Cloud functions . I have used `MYSQL` as the DB using `SEQUELIZE` and `Oauth-Server` , if anyone need those models , will share it through repo .

With this you can able to link account using your own Server which implements 
Auth tokens and Access Tokens

Comment: you refer to AUTHORIZATION_CODE - but where does this come from?

Comment: @JasonSilver this is auto generated by the resource serve

Comment: I think this really needs to mention that the secret sauce is that the "access_token" parameter should be called "code" instead, as well as the # being ? to denote the query start (but this last bit is actually fixed in their latest docs, it's jsut the access-token bit that's wrong)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the URL on this line isn't sending the parameters as *query* parameters, they're sending them as part of the *anchor*:

```
res.redirect('https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/xxxxxx#access_token=' + user._json.token + '&token_type=bearer&state=google')
```

You should replace the # with a ?, as illustrated here:

```
res.redirect('https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/xxxxxx?access_token=' + user._json.token + '&token_type=bearer&state=google')
```

Comment: now a different error message `Accounts failed to link. Please close your browser and try again`

Comment: Please update the original question to add what you change and what the results are after changes. You may also want to clarify what, exactly, you are doing to generate each error.

Comment: @Prisioner i have updated my question with the changes what i have done , and created a demo_app what i am trying to do .. thanks