# Google Assistant how can I keep signed in?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, actions-on-google

I'm developing a google assistant app, and I have implemented a google sign in with oauth2 code flow.

The thing here is that the assistant is supposed to refresh the access token automagically [as stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288981/how-to-authenticate-user-with-just-a-google-account-on-actions-on-google/44296039#44296039). The issue is that whenever my access token expires, I'm asked to link my account and "sign in" again instead of just refreshing the access token.

As you can see en number 1, I previously gave authorization to see me profile, it even greeted me by my name. After an hour or so, the Link to Google button is presented.

When I press the Link to Google button, I'm sent to to a chrome tab, but I don't need to press any button to grant permissions again, it rapidly shows a signing message and goes to google.com as soon as it finishes.

[image]

Comment: Can you update the question to include a screen shot of what the authorization screen looks like?

Comment: When I press the Link to Google button, I'm sent to to a chrome tab, but I don't need to press any button to grant permissions again, it rapidly shows a signing message and and goes to google.com as soon as it finishes