# Getting google user profile given the userID and Access Token

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

So, I have managed to link google user account to my agent on API.AI as per this [guide](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-code-flow) and found similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44296039) to this.

"Profile" and "Email" has been added as client scope.

Now, the assistant have been sending a userId and AccessToken to my fulfillment webhook, under originalRequest-> data-> inputs->user

Something like this:

```
"user":{
    "accessToken":"TWWM**********************bgf",
    "locale":"en-US",
    "userId":"AKL*********************exlT"
 }
```

So far my accesToken is always rendered invalid by Google.

If I check my token:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=TWWM**********************bgf
```

It renders as invalid

```
{
    "error_description": "Invalid Value"
}
```

How do I get the basic user profile information such as First Name, Last Name and Email given the above accessToken and UserId?

Which GoogleApi end point should I invoke?

Answer (score 2):

For starters, the `userId` field provided here is not a Google ID. It is an anonymous, Assistant specific, ID that is meant to be used to anonymously track a person between sessions, but which the user can revoke if they wish. It is not useful to get additional information through OAuth.

Next, keep in mind during your tests that the `accessToken` has a limited lifetime - usually about an hour. If you're testing after that hour, the endpoint you're trying to get info from will return an error. (And OAuth likes to be vague about what the error actually is.)

I'm not sure that the `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo` endpoint actually *accepts* an access token. At least I couldn't find any documentation that says that it does. It is mostly used to exchange other tokens *for* an access token.

You have a couple of options to get the information you want with the scopes you've requested. (And probably more than the two mentioned here.) In both of these cases, you'd pass the `accessToken` in an HTTP `Authorization` header:

```
Authorization: Bearer TWWM**********************bgf
```

Using the [Google People API](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/read-people#get-the-person-for-the-user) you'd be using the [people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) method. To get just the name and email address fields, you can use a URL such as

```
https://people.googleapi.com/v1/people/me?personFields=names,emailAddresses
```

The [plus.people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get) is similar, but returns the information in a different format. In this case, you'd use a URL such as

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
```

Comment: "It is mostly used to exchange other tokens for an access token" the token info endpoint is only used to get information about an `access_token`, `id_token` or `token_handle` (api explorer [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/oauth2/v2/oauth2.tokeninfo)). Most of the time it's used to check the validity of a token

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
GET https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ya29.A0A...ROsIKd49A
```

Response:

```
{
  "sub": "908584452000000000000",
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/default-user=s96-c"
}
```

Check this docs - https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#obtainuserinfo

```
sub - An identifier for the user, unique among all Google accounts and never reused. A Google account can have multiple email addresses at different points in time, but the sub value is never changed. Use sub within your application as the unique-identifier key for the user. Maximum length of 255 case-sensitive ASCII characters.
```