# Dialogflow Google Assistant Integration error - "Internal error encountered"

Tags: google-oauth, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I want to create a chatbot with Dialogflow and Google Assistant along with Google Transactions API for enabling a user to order some items. For now, specifically, I want to use `actions.intent.SIGN_IN` intent to connect another website account with Google Assistant. Because of this I have to perform all the configuration needed for Google account linking.

For this reason, I try the follow the steps of the first answer of this post: [How to authenticate user with just a Google account on Actions on Google?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288981/how-to-authenticate-user-with-just-a-google-account-on-actions-on-google).

I used Auth0 for getting an Authorization URL (`https://project_id.eu.auth0.com/authorize`) and a token URL (`https://project_id.eu.auth0.com/oauth/token`).

However, now I am stuck at the `Configure API.AI` part of this answer. 
Specifically, now when I press `Test` after I ticked the `Sign in required` box in Dialogflow Google Assistant integration I get this: 
[image]

Actually this error now occurs even if I untick the `Sign in required` box while apparently before doing all the linking account stuff I could properly test my Dialogflow app on the Google Assistant.

**Why am I getting this error and how can I fix this?**

**Does it has to do anything with the authentication details which I provided?**

**** **UPDATE** ****

Finally, I do not get this error as soon as I change `Linking type` from `OAuth & Google Sign In` to `OAuth` at `Google Actions Console` -> Left sidebar -> `ADVANCED OPTIONS` -> `Account linking`.

[image]

I do not know why this is occurring so anyone who wants to explain this to me is more than welcome :) .

Comment: Try a proxy URL and see if that works. `https://foo.com/o/oauth2/auth` -> `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth`. Use the `foo.com` URL in the form.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Hm, I am not really so sure that proxies are necessary now. Actually, I think that my authorisation url and url token are right according to the docs of Auth0. However, i am getting the error which you see at the image at the update.

Answer (score 2):

The StackOverflow answer you linked to has a notice on top that the procedures outlined were blocked as of October 2017.

It is missing an update (which I need to add) from the past couple of weeks that they have announced that you'll be able to use [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in) directly under some criteria. Assuming you meet the criteria, you'll be able to let your users just use Google Sign-In without having to setup any OAuth server (or specifying Google's servers as the OAuth server - that part is just assumed).

From the fix you discovered, it sounds like Google Sign-In isn't completely working internally yet as well, since it is in Developer Preview still. It could also be that other default settings weren't valid and were causing the problem.

But yes - if you're just going to be relying on an outside OAuth server, you can remove the "Google Sign In" part of the option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Prisoner (upvote).  (1) Oops, sorry, I did not exactly notice the update at the beginning of your post.  (2) I did not know this about `Google Sign-In` but if I am not wrong it does not change much to your answer at your post (?). (3) Regarding my last error, ok I  closed, signed out etc everything and re-launch them but I am still getting this error and I have no clue why exactly :(

Comment: Actually, I sort of solved this error. Please see my updated post above for more details.

Comment: Glad you got it working! (1) Not a problem, just wanted to make sure it was clear if anyone else came along. (2) I've updated it to clarify (I hope) what "Google Sign-In" offers.  (3) Removed my suggestion and added some more trying to clarify what you might have seen and why you have it working. But, again, mostly glad you figured the problem out!

Comment: Thanks :) . By the way @Prisoner, let me tell you the following: I have not seen anyone else yet on StackOverflow who consistently writes so analytical and well-structured answers. Also, it seems like you are always in a very good mood as a far as I can see from the tone of your answers/comments which is even more admirable!