# account linking process through Google Actions (token generation process through google actions)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

[mismatch redirect uri screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZrxT.png) [This is account linking screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9bmM.png) [This is error image with actual error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrQJX.png) How to link account through Google Actions?

(token generation process through google actions)

Generated Client Id & Client secret for Project but not able to construct the authoriztion URL in client information section of Account linking tab.

Account link process is not working as expected, showing error while enabling test in simulator (Error: We're sorry, but something went wrong. Please try again.)

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44296039/6763544)

Comment: Thanks Sairaj for your comment. We tried that but now stuck in the process where it shows error "400. That’s an error. Error: invalid_request Missing required parameter: scope" though we have added scopes in the https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent?project=<projName>&folder&organizationId&duration=ID. Can someone please guide how to get rid of this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We could help if you can edit the post and add a screenshot of account linking and where u get the error

Comment: Hi sairaj, Please find attached files. Added error screen image with an error description. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the screenshot of actual account linking configuration page ?

Comment: We have resolved the scope error and facing the problem of redirect_uri_mismatch in google api, I am stucked, what should be the Authorized redirect uri in Google API, for reference please find the attached image. Image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZrxT.png

Comment: I have resolved scope errors and redirect_uri_mismatch in google api. Authorize Url in account linking process was not correct. So entered correct url and completed the account linking process.